# mysql regex from point A to B

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace, sql-update

how do I remove the iframe tag using MySQL from the code below:

```
Hai, lasa-ma in lumea mea
Du-te nu ma astepta, pa-pa, pa-pa, pa-pa
Crede-ma-i mai bine asa
Poate ne intalnim candva, pa-pa, pa-pa, pa-pa</pre>
<pre width="80"></pre>
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GRXJuctr7Hk?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
```

I am using:

```
update wp_posts set post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/','');
```

But I want to remove all the iframe tags.
In php works by using regex, but in sql I don't have any idea how to do this.

Sorry for my bad English ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that this is a quick & dirty solution, but if you have at maximum only one iframe tag on your string, you can use something like this:

```
UPDATE
  wp_posts
SET
  post_content =
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content , '<iframe', 1),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content , '</iframe>', -1)
  )
```

The first SUBSTRING_INDEX will return everything at the left of the `<iframe` string, the second one everything at the right of the `</iframe>` string.

If there are more than one iframe, this is not going to work.